# How to fix "py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o22.isBarrier. Trace: py4j.Py4JException: Method isBarrier([]) does not exist"

Tags: pyspark

I have Pycharm 2018.2 and installed apache spark 2.3.3. I have installed Pyspark package 2.4.3. When executing program, i am getting the captioned error

```py
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import collections

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("RatingsHistogram")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

lines = sc.textFile("file:///SparkCourse/ml-100k/u.data")

ratings = lines.map(lambda x: x.split()[2]) #--> the error comes when executing this line

result = ratings.countByValue()

sortedResults = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(result.items()))
for key, value in sortedResults.items():
    print("%s %i" % (key, value))

the actual output is count of movies as per rating
1 6110
2 11370
3 27145

i got this result when i ran the program in enthought canopy command prompt but i am getting error in pycharm
```

Comment: can you share sample input data? I suppose it might be failing because you don't have 3 word in some lines (split() without an argument - splits per space)...

Comment: i have added the entire program as well as the output

Comment: Try pyspark 2.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue--and I'm working through the very same udemy course you are. When I changed the version of pyspark that PyCharm had installed to 2.3.x, the error was resolved.